# SQL Server DMV table dm_exec_requests, elapsed_time, cpu_time, wait_time

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

In SQL Server DMV table dm_exec_requests, should the following be true:

```
total_elapsed_time = cpu_time + wait_time
```

Thanks,
Rafi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not equal. As stated on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177648.aspx):

> cpu_time - CPU time in milliseconds that is used by the request. Is not nullable.

and

> wait_time - If the request is currently blocked, this column returns the duration in milliseconds, of the current wait. Is not nullable.

As You can see, wait_time is duration of **current** wait and You may have multiple waits during query execution.